# How do I avoid obstacles on a predefined path?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I want is a character to walk along a path defined as a waypoint sequence. For example, a soldier patrolling around a castle.

However, I want the soldier to avoid (dynamic) obstacles, without deviating from the path too much.

[image: Patrol route without obstruction]
[image: Obstructed patrol route and corrected path]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove from the path any waypoints that lie inside the obstacle and then use your favorite pathfinding routine to connect the waypoints remaining on each side.